# setAction: in NSViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

*It might be helpful to know that I come from a iOS background and that this is one of my first OS X projects.*

In my project, I have a NSView subclass and a NSViewController and load the view in the controller.

```
- (void)loadView
{
    StartView *view = [StartView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; // frame exists
    self.view = view;
}
```

The view has a `NSButton`-property `btnNew`that I add in `initWithFrame:`.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.btnNew = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSRectFromCGRect(CGRectMake(350, 180, 300, 60))];

        [self addSubview:self.btnNew];
    }

    return self;
}
```

In `loadView:` I try to set the action and target.

```
- (void)loadView
{
    StartView *view = [StartView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; // frame exists

    [view.btnNew setTarget:self];
    [view.btnNew setAction:@selector(createNew:)];

    self.view = view;
}
```

The `createNew:` function exists, off course.

However, when clicking the button, the app crashes. When I move the `setTarget:` and the `setAction:` into the view and perform them on `self.btnNew`, it works, but I think that's not how you should work with events and user interaction in a decent MVC-architecture.

The problem is with the `self` in `[view.btnNew setTarget:self];`, I guess. If I grab the target with `view.btnNew.target`, this is a nil object (0x000…000). `Self` exists & `view.btnNew` exists.

Am I doing something wrong? Or should I really listen to the click in the view and work with a delegate or a notification (I guess not?)

Comment: What exception is raised, what is the stack trace and the message?

Comment: @Wain

It raises an 'NSObject does not respond to selector'-exception, probably because the target is nil somehow.

I also tried wrapping the setTarget and setAction in an if-clause with [self respondsToSelector:] but that was true so the action still gets bound.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're doing anything wrong.mwhat retains the controller while the view is on display?

Comment: @Wain I answered my own question, see below. The problem was indeed that the retain count of the controller got to zero before the click happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it out myself, with help from [Niel Deckx](http://mrdckx.be/).

The problem was **ARC**. The ViewController got dealloced before the click happened, which explains the *NSObject does not respond to selector*: the target doesn't exist anymore.

The easy solution is to have the ViewController as a (strong?) property where you create it.